# The good practice for file downloading with laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, download, response

I'm making an app based on file uploads and downloads. Currently for the file download with AJAX I get the name of the file to be downloaded, pass it to the server-side and return the path which I append to a html `<a></a>` tag.

```
public function downloadUserFile(){
        mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
        $ds = DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
        $userid = Auth::id();
        $filename = htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['filename']);
        $entry = File::where('filename', $filename)->firstOrFail();

        $onlyFilename = substr($filename, 0, strrpos($filename, "."));
        $type = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\File::extension(storage_path().'uploads'.$ds.$userid.$ds.$filename);
        $filenameVersion = $onlyFilename.'_0'.'.'.$type;

        $file = Storage::disk()->get('uploads'.$ds.$userid.$ds.$filenameVersion);
        $path = $userid.'/'.$filenameVersion;
        $arr = array('path' => $path, 'filename' => $filename);
        return json_encode($arr);                
}
```

I've also seen people use `readfile()` or `response()->download()` (although I still can't understand how to use `response()-download()`). So what would be the best way to achieve a file download logic?

Comment: That depends on your requirements, if all files are directly reachable through a path, everybody can see them. If you need to protect the contents and only serve under specific conditions (authentication for example), you need to store them out of the web-root and serve them through php.

Comment: @jeroen Well they shouldn't be visible for everybody.

Comment: I can imagine :-) So you need to store them out of the web-root and request them through a php file where you can put your logic. And if you can serve the file, you read it and output it directly from php. A small search here should give you plenty of examples.

Comment: Maybe I can save you some time/struggles, you can't initiate a file download via ajax which may very well be the reason why you can't get `response()->download()` to work.

Comment: @user3158900 That would be fanstastic!